# AndroidViewModel is killed on orientation change in background

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am using an activity X which uses an implementation Y of AndroidViewModel to store/access some data. Now, when the device orientation is changed while activity X is in foreground, activity X is recreated but view model Y is kept live which is expected.

Consider below scenario-
1) Open app and launch the activity X which creates view model Y
2) Switch to some other app and change orientation
3) Now switch back to app

Expectation - Activity X should be destroyed and recreated because of orientation changes but the view model Y should remain live

Actual - Activity X is recreated as expected but view model Y is also killed.

Please suggest solution to fix the same.

In my activity X's onCreate() method, code looks something like below:
ViewModelY = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelY.class);

Comment: share relevant code as in how you are creating viewmodels in activities

Comment: Possibly the whole app is killed when switching to another app and rotating device.

Comment: @Demigod - I am not sure of the same but my activity X's finish() method is not called. It is destroyed and recreated as done in simple orientation changes case.

Comment: Your activity method `finish()` will never be called when the system will kill the app in the background(in fact it supposed to be used by you only,when you want to exit from the activity), you can check it with your `Application` instance which should stay the same, when returning from other app

Comment: @Demigod - I verified app is not getting killed. Do you suspect anything else?

Comment: @AshishGoyal, can you post code of your Activity (that part that related to view model instance, etc.)?